# WordPress Following? Social Users?

Tags: plugins, rss

I'm building an extensive user backend on a WordPress news website.  One of the features I've noticed many major sites have is the ability for logged in users to follow headlines from users or categories they select.

Forbes took the technology from TrueSlant in its acquisition and I know as a fact it is WordPress.

Is there a similar plugin or tutorial that can help me achieve the same?  I've been looking and can't find one.

Examples:
http://blogs.forbes.com/luisakroll/
http://trueslant.com/level/
Mashable.com (if you login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you know about [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org) or not, but they have a plugin that will help you in your quest.

It is called [BuddyPress Followers](http://buddypress.org/community/groups/buddypress-followers/) which allows users to follow peoples activity. It should have options in it to only follow posts and whatnot.

BuddyPress also makes WordPress more "Social"

Comment: I am aware of BuddyPress.  In your opinion, do you think these sites are simply using that plugin?  Thanks for letting me know about that, I hadn't come across that plugin yet.

Comment: Do you know any WordPress-only (no BuddyPress) solutions?